# Handling possible errors with network drive file I/O

Tags: windows, networking, file, error-handling

I'm trying to make file I/O over a network drive (likely over a WAN or VPN) as reliable as possible for a native C++ Windows app...

What are the possible error conditions that I need to be able to handle?

How can I simulate these error conditions in testing?

How do I get detailed information on a particular error?  For example, if `fopen()` fails, does `errno` tell me everything I need to know, or do I need to get at the `GetLastError()` value?

How do I reliably distinguish between "network drive access fully functional but the file doesn't exist" and various problems with the network or server?

One particular error condition that I've noticed on my desktop (not specific to the app we're developing) is that sometimes the first attempt to access a file on a network drive will fail, but it presumably causes the drive to be reconnected in the background, because subsequent connections work.  I don't know what causes this.  This is an example of the kind of error condition that I want to properly handle.

**EDIT:** This is for a legacy distributed application that uses files on network shares for communication between nodes.  Some nodes may be unattended, so passing the error on to the end user may not be an option.  The long term goal is to switch to a better protocol, but in the short term I'd like to make the file I/O as reliable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're approaching this from a wrong perspective. There's little one can do in the application itself to improve what is essentially a network filesystem driver problem, perhaps except implementing the networked I/O itself. That being said, you should be better off choosing a suitable networked filesystem for your needs. Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_file_systems) on Wikipedia.

Generally, your application should behave like the file is locally-stored. Don't try too hard to handle network problems. But if your choice of a network filesystem is good, then these problems can be automatically mitigated.

So I'd say you should settle with checking *errno* in case of errors. Perhaps fallback on  local storage in case writing a remote file fails (if the networked file system doesn't handle this itself).

Comment: Switching our customers to a new network filesystem would be hard, but you have helped me rethink how and why we're using the networked files and how we ought to handle errors.  Thanks.